# Search into a Table

Tags: angular, typescript

Via WebService im sending to the front-end an Json and mapping it for putting all its content into a table and i want to Establish a Search method for viewing only the rows having the searched letters.

Component.ts

```
allCountries:allCountries[];
applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.allCountries.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ERROR
```

mapping

```
export class allCountries{
    name:string;
    iso2:string;
    iso3:string;
    unicode:string;
    dial:string;
    currency:string;
    capital:string;
    continent:string;
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-label for="ricerca">Ricerca</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" name="searchString" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Type to search..." />

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="allCountries">

            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nazione</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let allCountries">{{allCountries.name}}</td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="iso2">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>iso 2</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let allCountries">{{allCountries.iso2}}</td>
                </ng-container>
```

error

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ <S extends allCountries>(callbackfn: (value: allCountries, index: number, array: allCountries[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (callbackfn: (value: allCountries, index: number, array: allCountries[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): allCountries[]; }'.
```

i'm getting that the error is because "filter" is available for simple arrays and not for arrays of objects.
I didnt post all the code because it would have been useless since isn't connected to my problem.
Thanks for the Help

Comment: where are you setting the value of `this.allCountries` ? Put a breakpoint in the line where you are doing this `this.allCountries = ...` and very likelly you will see that it is not an array that is being assigned to that var.

Comment: allCountries=allCountries[ ], practically i'm assigning the value of this variable to the mapper of the json incoming from a webService. the problem is that filter or also sort is applicable only to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `Array.filter` is a function and not a property. So it cannot be assigned like that: `this.allCountries.filter =` .

Instead, one should call it as a function, passing as an argument another function that will do the filtering.

Example of filtering for countries that have the typed substring in its name (function `String.includes()`:

```
  this.filteredCountries = this.allCountries.filter(
      obj => obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.trim().toLowerCase())    
  );
```

It is a good idea to keep two separated arrays, one immutable with all the countries (`allCountries`) and another one that has the given filtered countries according to the text typed (ex: `filteredCountries`). Otherwise each filtering cycle will reduce the array and eventually the array of countries will be empty.

This is the general idea:

```
export class AppComponent {
  allCountries = [
    {
      name: "England"
    },
    {
      name: "France"
    }
  ];

  filteredCountries = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredCountries = this.allCountries;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (!filterValue) {
      //empty filter, show all countries:
      this.filteredCountries = this.allCountries;
    } else {
      console.log("Filtering for " + filterValue);
      this.filteredCountries = this.allCountries.filter(
        obj => obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And in the html instead of `allCountries` one should bind to `filteredCountries`:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="filteredCountries">

  <!-- code omitted for brevity -->

</table>
```

Here is a stackblitz with the working code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lzkxnr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you very much bro, you saved me a lot of time <3